# Facebook Page Profile Picture upload doesn't work. How can be uploaded a page picture?

Tags: image, facebook, upload, profile

I try to upload a facebook page profile picture.

1. If i'm using a public picture url on the internet, the upload works, so the picture is updated. Although it helps me not, as i'd like to upload my own page profile picture.

So this call looks like to work, as the page profile picture is updated:

`curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/picture?access_token=[access_token]&picture=https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png"`

Although surprisingly the following error comes:

`{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"ACYX59xl8QtGpvK6wozgxUb"}}`

2. If i'm using a REST GET webservice call to my application, which returns with the same picture as Point 1) it doesn't work. The *https://fkesh.ngrok.io/profilePicture/pageProfilePic.png* is the GET webservice call.

`curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/picture?access_token=[access_token]&picture=https://fkesh.ngrok.io/profilePicture/pageProfilePic.png"`

Sorrowfully the following error is coming, and the picture won't be uploaded:

`{"error":{"message":"(#1) Could not fetch picture","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"A841VXO47expQy08MWoN3uF"}}`

3. The best would be the possibility to upload the picture from a stream/file, but the upload doesn't work neither:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -d "@pool.png" "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/picture?access_token=[access_token]"`

The same error is coming, as Point 2):

`{"error":{"message":"(#1) Could not fetch picture","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"AT3MqnpHjGyqm1akujpOsEa"}}`

How would be possible to make Point 2) or 3) to work?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/picture/#Creating says, _“`picture` - URL - URL of the picture to upload”_, so I would assume a file upload isn’t actually possible in this place. There doesn’t seem to be a `source` parameter, and it does not mentiond file uploads anywhere.

Comment: But there is `photo - numeric string - ID of the photo to use as the profile pic` - so I guess you could try and upload a photo to the page first, and then use the id of that photo to set the new profile pic. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating explicitly supports file uploads.